# HTML form to SQLITE database as a new record, using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, database, forms, sqlite

So far I’ve made a form in html (in pycharm)
I also have a database in sqlite (in pycharm)
When someone fills in the form, i need to insert the inputs into the sqlite database, as a new record. Is it possible to do this in pycharm? and do i use javascript? pls help me
thanks

Comment: PyCharm is an IDE aka "fancy editor". It doesn't "do anything" for program execution.. this would be a good time to *follow some tutorials*; learning some base knowledge will enable asking *focused* questions on actual [implementation] issues. There will be lots of relevant information found with queries like "Python create SQL website" or "Python web framework".

Comment: I don't see how an IDE is relevant for storing something in a DB. We do need some code and a specific error not a question of how to.

Comment: thanks @user2864740 im also not 5